# Find limit or prove there isn't any for $a_{n + 1} = 1 + \frac{a^m_n}{1 + a_n} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

$$a_{1} = 1 \ \ \ \ \ a_{n+1} = 1 + \frac{a^{m}_{n}}{1 + a_{n}} \ \ n \in \mathbb{N}^{*} \  m = 0, 1, 2, ..$$

So first I'll check when it is increasing or decreasing:
$$a_{n} \leq 1 + \frac{a^{m}_{n}}{1 + a_{n}}$$
$$a_{n} -1\leq  \frac{a^{m}_{n}}{1 + a_{n}}$$
Because $a_{n} \geq 1 $ we can multiply both sides by $1 + a_{n}$ 
$$a_{n}^{2} \leq 1 + a^{m}_{n}$$

I guess I kind of got it for $m = 0$ and $m = 1$ Now I will focus on part where $m \geq 2$

Since $a_{n} \geq 1 $ $$ \forall n \in \mathbb{N^*} \ \ a_{n}^{2} \leq1 + a^{m}_{n}$$

So it is increasing. So now how to prove that there is no limit? ( $lim = + \infty)$

Comment: Note that you mix up $a_n$ and $a_{n + 1}$ all over the place, I fixed some but you have to clean up the rest of the derivation. I can't possibly guess what you mean to do.

Comment: Try some values and see what happens...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can conside $$\frac{a_n^p}{n}=\frac{a_n^p-a_{n-1}^p}{n-(n-1)
}$$,determine p